# Replace a ? with " nothing " and fetch the original string again

Tags: java, regex, string

This is the Code , I am trying to use the regular expression to get the  original String back

```
        String str = "Hai ? hello : abc ^ ";

   str = str.replaceAll("[?]+","");

   System.out.println("1"+str);

   String str2 = str.replaceAll("['']+","?");

   System.out.println("2"+str2);
```

What should be the regular expression to get back the original string

Comment: How could you possibly get back to the original? You've lost information. (It's also not really clear why you'd want to use regular expressions here.)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hai ? hello : abc ^ ";
String str1 = str.replaceAll("[?]+",""); 
System.out.println("1"+str1); 
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("['']+","?"); 
System.out.println("2"+str2);
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Str2 is not giving the original String in this case

Comment: @KAPILPATIL - String `str` is original. Strings `str1` and `str2` are modified based on `replaceAll` request(s).

Answer (score 0):

You must to replace the replacement pattern because you lost information in the first replacement

```
String str = "Hai ? hello : abc ^ ";
String str1 = str.replaceAll("?","|"); 
System.out.println("1"+str1); 
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("|","?"); 
System.out.println("2"+str2);
```